# Diffraction grating interference question

Tags: waves

[image]

When deriving the equation for diffraction grating, I was told that all the dotted arrows interfere with each other, and given that assumption, the rest of derivation was fine.
But why do they all interfere with each other? They're not on top of each other - they're in different position so how would they affect each other?

Thanks

Comment: They're not *strictly, strictly* parallel, only *very, very almost*. Where they finally meet up (e.g. the retina of your eye) that's where they then interact.

Comment: If that is what you were told, then you were told something that is 100% wrong. The dotted arrows are not interfering with each other. What does interfere are the (almost cylindrical) wavefronts that emanate from each slit. The dotted arrows are merely approximations for the phase shifts of those wave fronts, so you end up with the right result based on wrong reasoning.